# MediaStore.Action_Image_Capture preview blurry issue when i use in android N

Tags: android, image

Blur Image(Android N)

Android 6 or below don't have this issues.
I try the different api version already.

Anyone can provide any information?

Answer (score 0):

You will only get thumbnail in Android N. There is a new way of getting full sized image. Take a look at the docs
https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Comment: I understand it return thumbnail, if i just want preview it full screen without blur and submit it to server. The resources above can be done?

Comment: I apply that sample code to it alrdy, it still the same

Comment: Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, actionCode);

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue on some SAMSUNG devices, the preview was blurry and the resulting image as well so we changed the code to use FileProvider to store the image on a file using the following guide:

https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954

And it was fixed.

So you basically need to create a file using the file provider and set it on the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```